# Slide object using For Loop (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation

I did quite a bit of searching around and didn't find anything of much help.

Is it possible to "slide" or "move" using C#, an object from one Location to another using a simple For loop?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. What type of application? Console, Windows, Web?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you rather use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). There are other options, but this will be the simplist if you want to avoid threading issues etc.

Using a straight for loop will require that you pump the message queue using `Application.DoEvents()` to ensure that windows has the opportunity to actually render the updated control otherwise the for loop would run to completion without updating the UI and the control will appear to jump from the source location to the target location.

Here is a QAD sample for animating a button in the Y direction when clicked. This code assumes you  put a timer control on the form called `animationTimer`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!animationTimer.Enabled)
  {
    animationTimer.Interval = 10;
    animationTimer.Start();
  }
}

private int _animateDirection = 1;
private void animationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y + _animateDirection);

  if (button1.Location.Y == 0 || button1.Location.Y == 100)
  {
    animationTimer.Stop();
    _animateDirection *= -1; // reverse the direction
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the circumstances of course, but I agree that it seems likely that using a Timer would be useful for whatever he wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the object you're talking about is some kind of `Control` you could just change the `Location` property of it.

So something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ctrl.Location.X += i;
}
```

Should work I think.